# Location is displayed in Map

Tags: android, dictionary

Hey Guys i was just trying to make an application to display my location on google map.i tried running this code for displaying my current location in google map but it isnt displaying anything on the Map(it is displaying the  map but not the location)
The application is runnng but the location marker is not there.please help

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
 OnMapReadyCallback {
 LatLng  myPosition;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 

   getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}




@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mFusedLocationClient = 
 LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);



    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
 ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Task task= mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {


                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"code run here",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (location != null) {
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        String a,b;
                        a= String.valueOf(latitude);
                        b= String.valueOf(longitude);

                        Log.d(a,b);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),a+b,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        googleMap.addMarker(new 
 MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("Start"));

 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the fine and coarse location in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

also do call the requestPermisiion method if permission is not given.

Comment: when you started the app , was there any popup asking for permission?

Comment: if not then go to settings -> your app-> permissions and enable them manually. and relaunch the app

Comment: well restarting the app did the magic i guess even after all these i was supposed to restart Android Studio